# Show that the system x′ =g(x), and y′ =f(x)y has at most one solution on any interval, for a given initial value. (Hint: use Gronwall’s inequality.)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Can someone help me out with this?

This is a problem of ODE involving Gronwall's inequality and also showing that 2 ODE's x' and y' have at most one solution on any interval (please consider any interval for example [0,A] or [A,B]) for a given initial value. I tried to prove this using gronwalls inequality and also by calculating x and y from the 2 equations but its not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have edited the question, kindly check and let me know if there is any concern. Kindly feel free to ask me any questions if you have.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math formatting. This is probably part of the reason people have voted your question to be closed. It can be reopened if you do the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $(x_1(t),y_1(t))$ and $(x_2(t),y_2(t))$ to be two solutions to the IVP on the interval $I = [0,T]$. Let $D_1(t) = (x_2(t)-x_1(t))^2$. Then notice that

$$D_1'(t) = 2(x_2-x_1)(x_2'-x_1') = 2(x_2-x_1)(g(x_2)-g(x_1)) \le 2|x_2-x_1||g(x_2)-g(x_1)| \le 2L(x_2-x_1)^2 = 2LD_1(t)$$

by Gronwall's we then have

$$D_1(t) \le D_1(0) e^{2Lt} = 0$$

since $D_1(0) =(x_2(0)-x_1(0))^2 = 0^2 = 0$. Thus $D_1(t) = 0$ for all $t$ in interval $I$ since $D(t)$ is non-negative so $x_2 = x_1$ on $I$.

Similarly consider $D_2(t) = (y_2(t)-y_1(t))^2$

Then

$$D_2'(t) = 2(y_2-y_1)(y_2'-y_1') = 2(y_2-y_1)(f(x_1)y_1 - f(x_2)y_2)$$

We just showed before that $x_1 = x_2$ in the interval thus

$$= 2(y_2-y_1)(f(x_1)y_1-f(x_1)y_2) = 2(y_2-y_1)^2f(x_1) \le 2(y_2-y_1)^2 |f(x_1)|$$

Note that $|f(x_1(t))|$ is continuous and since we are on a closed and bounded interval $I$, it achieves a maximum, $M$. Thus,

$$D_2'(t) \le 2MD_2(t)$$

A similar Gronwall's argument from before shows that $D_2(t) = 0$ for all $t$ in $I$ so $y_2 = y_1$ for all $t \in I$. This proves the claim.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I have few questions to ask you on this. Can you please explain how you got (D1(t)≤D1(0)e2Lt=0) using Gronwalls inequality? Whats the value of delta and epsilon in this that gives you this result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AshisJana What form of Gronwall's Inequality do you know? There are many versions out there. The one I know says if $u'(t) \le \beta(t) u(t)$ on an interval $[a,b]$ then $u(t) \le u(a) \exp\left( \int_a^t \beta(s) ds \right)$ for $ t\in [a,b]$. So applying that to $D_1'(t) \le 2LD_1(t)$ gives $D_1(t) \le D_1(0) e^{2Lt}$. Then, we use that since $x_1,x_2$ solve the same IVP that $x_1(0) = x_2(0)$ so $D_1(0) = (x_2(0)-x_1(0))^2 = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, thats the one I used too. Maybe i did a calculation mistake somewhere thats why I got different answers. Sorry for that, but thanks a lot for your response.